# Pass hidden params into a link_to to prefill a new create form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to prefill some fields in my create form.

For now i pass into my Link_to some params and it works well but the user can change those parmas directly in the url and that can cause problems.

How can i pass some hidden information into my link_to ?

Thank you,

Comment: Add `:method => "post"` to your `link_to` then the parameters will not shown in the url

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it is for a new_path: new_RESOURCE_path() and it doesn't seem to have a POST route.

Comment: Ok then you can use `form's hidden_field` section to send hidden values right

Comment: When i use form_tag the hidden values are still shown in the URL

Comment: please add your route here for `new_path: new_RESOURCE_path()`

Comment: Not the answer directly, but you should consider not passing params that can cause problems from the client at all. Even with POST request, it's easy to see and modify those params in the web inspector.